# React Native: Refresh Controll not working with ScrollView

Tags: react-native

I would like to pull down a scrollView and refresh this component, so I have followed the official document mentioning onRefresh and RefreshContorol from react-n

refresh does workout but scroll is not working. However when i remove `contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}` scroll start working but refresh control does not work then. is there any way to resolve this?

```
export default function App() {
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = React.useState(false);

  const onRefresh = React.useCallback(() => {
    setRefreshing(true);

    wait(2000).then(() => setRefreshing(false));
  }, [refreshing]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
        }
      >
        <Text>Pull down to see RefreshControl indicator</Text>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },
  scrollView: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 20):

Make sure you use `ScrollView` from React Native instead of React Native Gesture Handler.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You need a little more upvotes, automatic import got me

Comment: exactly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but what I found was I had an empty list, so there was nothing rendered in the list for the "refresh control" to grab the drag motion from.

I changed my scroll list render to include a

"No items found" render and then it immediately started working.

So for refresh control you always have to have something in your list rendered to give the scroll view some height!

NOTE: I use styled components and my MessageView has a large height so it takes up most of the screen.

```js
<ScrollView
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            enabled={!myAppointmentLoading}
            refreshing={false}
            onRefresh={() => {
              console.log('Do refresh');
              refreshAppointmentList && refreshAppointmentList();
            }}
          />
        }>
        {appointments?.length > 0 ? (
          appointments.map(apt => (
            <AppointmentCard
              appointment={apt}
              key={`apt-${apt?.appointmentData?.appointmentId}`}
            />
          ))
        ) : (
          <MessageView>
            <MessageText>No upcoming appointments</MessageText>
          </MessageView>
        )}
      </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

here is sncak works fine.it doesnt work because contentContainerStyle is the child view.

```
import  React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,ScrollView, RefreshControl} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
const wait = (timeout) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));
}
export default function App() {
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = React.useState(false);
const data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,90,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]
  const onRefresh = React.useCallback(() => {
    setRefreshing(true);

    wait(2000).then(() => setRefreshing(false));
  }, [refreshing]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
        }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for reply. I tried using your solution but it's not working(Scroll not working). Can you please explain me how is it working for you

Comment: thats weird are you using this component as child component anywhere else!look this snack https://snack.expo.io/@msadman/quiet-pizza

Comment: yeah, I'm using this as a child component in another component

Comment: can u share the whole code where u using it i can help then